# str_subset with curly curly in R

Tags: r, stringr, rlang

I've a small function to read in files with certain string using `str_subset` which works if I pass the argument in quotes but I want to able to do it without. I thought I could do this with curly curly but isn't working.

Working example passing with quotes:

```
#creating csv file
library(tidyverse)
write_csv(mtcars, "C:\\Users\\testSTACK.csv")


#reading function
read_in_fun <- function(x) {

  setwd("C:\\Users")
  d <- list.files()   #lists all files in folder
  file <- d %>% 
    str_subset(pattern = x)

  #read in
  df <- read_csv(file)

  arg_name <- deparse(substitute(x)) 
  var_name <- paste("df_new", arg_name, sep = "_") 
  assign(var_name, df, env = .GlobalEnv) 

}

read_in_fun("STACK")

#this works, returns df called:
df_new_"STACK"
```

now if i try to be able to pass with no quotes using curly curly approach:

```
read_in_fun <- function(x) {

  setwd("C:\\Users")
  d <- list.files()   #lists all files in folder
  file <- d %>% 
    str_subset(pattern = {{x}})

  #read in
  df <- read_csv(file)

  arg_name <- deparse(substitute(x)) 
  var_name <- paste("df_new", arg_name, sep = "_") 
  assign(var_name, df, env = .GlobalEnv) 

}
read_in_fun(STACK)
#Error in type(pattern) : object 'STACK' not found
```

also tried using `enquo`

```
read_in_fun <- function(x) {

  x_quo <- enquo(x)


  setwd("C:\\Users")
  d <- list.files()   #lists all files in folder
  file <- d %>% 
    str_subset(pattern = !! as_label(x_quo)) #OR !!(x_quo)

  #read in
  df <- read_csv(file)

  arg_name <- deparse(substitute(x)) 
  var_name <- paste("df_new", arg_name, sep = "_") 
  assign(var_name, df, env = .GlobalEnv) 

}
read_in_fun(STACK)
# Error during wrapup: Quosures can only be unquoted within a quasiquotation context.
```

My desired output is a `df` called `df_new_STACK`. Can curly curly be used in this way? Thanks

Comment: Are you just trying to pass in a string? What are you passing in without quotes if not a string? [Curly-curly](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/) has a much different use case, typically to refer to columns in a data frame.

Comment: I'm trying to pass in unquoted string e.g. `read_in_fun(STACK)`. yes curly curly can be used for filtering columns and i thought `str_subset` could be thought of as an extension of this in this case. Here i'm filtering `d`?

Comment: Curly-curly doesn't filter columns, it allows you to refer to column names. Please read [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) about non-standard evaluation. If all you want is `df_new_STACK`, just do `var_name <- paste("df_new", x, sep = "_")` and don't use `deparse(substitute())` and pass in a string.

Comment: I don't want to pass a quoted string though. Id like to run `read_in_fun(STACK)` instead of `read_in_fun("STACK")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ensym` should work.

```
read_in_fun <- function(x) {

  x_sym <- ensym(x)

  d <- list.files()   
  file <- d %>% 
    str_subset(pattern = as_label(x_sym)) 

  #read in
  df <- read_csv(file)

  arg_name <- deparse(substitute(x)) 
  var_name <- paste("df_new", arg_name, sep = "_") 
  assign(var_name, df, env = .GlobalEnv) 

}

read_in_fun(STACK)

df_new_STACK
```