# How to use curly-curly operator and group by function

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I am learning R and trying to write functions that operate with column names as arguments. I am using rlang, and I need help understanding why am I getting some unexpected results when using the curly-curly operator and a group by function.

I don't understand why the second code chunk with the curly-curly doesn't work as I expect, any insight would be much appreciated. I am sorry if I made any mistake presenting the question or it is quite simple, I am learning.

Thank you so much.

This piece of code provides the desired result, with n counts for each different value found in the column "HLA_allele":

```
group_function <- function(.data, x_column){
  
  .data %>%
    group_by(.data[[x_column]]) %>%
    summarise(count = n())
}
```

Calling the function:
`group_function (selectedA, "HLA_allele")` 
Output (expected):

```
# A tibble: 19 × 2

    HLA_allele count
    \<chr\>      \<int\>
    1 01            43
    2 02           113
    3 03            53
    4 11            31
    5 23            19
    6 24            53
    7 25            12
    8 26            18
    9 29            55
    10 30            27
    11 31            11
    12 32            20
    13 33            10
    14 34             3
    15 36             1
    16 66             1
    17 68            14
    18 69             3
    19 80             1
```

However, when I try to use the curly-curly operator I get one single result as shown:

```
group_function <- function(.data, x_column){
  
  .data %>%
    group_by({{x_column}}) %>%
    summarise(count = n())
}
```

Calling the function:
`group_function (selectedA, "HLA_allele")` 
Output (unexpected):

```
# A tibble: 1 × 2

`"HLA_allele"` count
\<chr\>          \<int\>
1 HLA_allele       488
```

I've used ensym() as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61015854/str-subset-with-curly-curly-in-r), and it works, but I don't really understand what's going on or why curly doesn't work here as expected.

Comment: Indirection; Difference between using symbolic and character names. Check https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#indirection to see how to do the two

Comment: `{{` is meant to be used with unquoted column names, i.e. your function will work when you call `group_function (selectedA, HLA_allele)`. When you want to pass a column name as a string then the `tidyverse` team recommends to use the `.data` pro-noun as in your first approach. See https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/#the-good-and-bad-of-tidy-evaluation